# How to use Parsed XML file in HTML

Tags: html, web, xml-parsing

I have data stored in an XML file, that I want to use to create a website (HTML file). The following is a the format of the xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
<dblp>
  <article mdate="2017-05-28" key="journals/acta/Saxena96">
    <author>Sanjeev Saxena</author>
    <title>Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.
    </title>
    <pages>607-619</pages>
    <year>1996</year>
    <volume>33</volume>
    <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
    <number>7</number>
    <url>db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96</url>
    <ee>https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466</ee>
  </article>
```

I am following a tutorial on using SAX parser with JAVA in order to parse the XML file, where in the end I collect all the authors in a list or so. However I don't understand once I parse the XML file how will I use it in HTML in order to create a page where I display the names of the authors and so on. 
PS: My XML file is large (2.3 GB). I am new to web development so I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience. I use `TemplateLoader` from Hapax and use `TemplateDataDictionary` to set the variable to a dynamic value.
The user can check the link below to get detail.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/hapax2/wikis/Language.wiki#Variableg

Goodluck.